# Redirect ALL packet coming to port 60300 to gw 10.8.0.1 and/or dev tun0 using iproute2 and iptables

Tags: routes, vpn, iptables

I want to forward all packet coming to port 60300 to tun0.
Quick scheme:

internet -> myserver:60300 -> tun0<sub>myserver</sub> -> 10.8.0.1 -> 10.8.0.2.

I wanted to do that with this:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -m --dports 60300 -j ROUTE --oif tun0
```

then I learned the ROUTE target is a big fat lie so people can laugh at noobs like me.

After some quick search it turned out this is also possible with mark:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -m --dports 60300 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

and the use of iproute2, something like that:

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table (nb?)
```

This is where I struggle. Are there any easier solution? Btw I'm running Debian 6.0 with security updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -d myserver --destination-port 60300 -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.2:60300
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i eth0 -d myserver --destination-port 60300 -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.2:60300
```

...

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference between NAT routing and iproute2. 
As long as you mark the packet, it can be processed by routing table. 
The difference is in the destination address. 
If you use NAT, packet destination address will be changed to 10.8.0.2
In case of iproute2 usage, 10.8.0.2 will be just the next hop without changing destination address. 
So, it can be said that these solutions have different background. 
1. In case of NAT routing, the packet will arrive to tun0 and then targeted directly to 10.8.0.2 - it is good to use when the packet arrives from some network and you need to target it directly to the end point. Routing table will be used only to choose proper interface/gateway. 
2. It is better to use iproute2 for flexible traffic routing with keeping target IP (for instance, to balance outgoing traffic). In this case, routing table will lookup for the marked packed (for instance) and route it according to the proper rule. Of course, packet mark will not pass to the next hop.
It is really difficult for the first time to understand policy routing ideology, however it contains only 3 basic things that can make it simple:
- /etc/iproute2/rt_tables - this file keeps all information about tables and their priority. Once added, custom table will be stored in routing table.
- ip rule list - this command shows all actual rules that participate in policy routing.
- ip route show table XXX - shows all routing rules for the table. If no default route set in this table, all unmatched packets will be processed by main routing table. 
It is wrong to compare iproute2 vs NAT - they solve different tasks and usable in different situations.